# How to hex decode in php?

Tags: php

I got this string which is I guess Hex encoded:

```
<?
$s="&#x6c;&#x65;&#x63;&#x68;&#x61;&#x75";
echo chr(hexdec($s))

?>
```

How can I decode it ?

Comment: What is the expected result? Maybe just `hexdec($s)`? When I run that I get `119182715281781`

Comment: They are html encoded unicode characters.

Answer (score 2):

They are HTML encoded unicode characters, not a hex-encoded string. To decode this, you can use [`html_entity_decode()`](https://www.php.net/html_entity_decode), as follows:

```
echo html_entity_decode($s);
```

Will produce:

```
lechau
```