# PHP Encoding and Decode

Tags: php, encoding, decode

I have a slice of php encoded code but I don't know how it encoded i mean by which why they encoded this code when i use [unphp.net](https://unphp.net) successfully it decode the code and get the real code 
simple of encoded code `define("\x53\x54\117\103\113\x5f\103\x48\105\x43\113", false)` my question is how i can encode another code to be like this and it by which why is encoded please anyone have a knowledge about tell me or know any tool to suggest

Comment: this answer may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21575592/how-to-hex-decode-in-php. I managed to decode this with `html_entity_decode()`

Comment: You can also decode it by copying it to `echo` as in `echo "\x53\x54\117\103\113\x5f\103\x48\105\x43\113"; // STOCK_CHECK`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would need more information for me to be able to discern what obfuscator was actually used to encode this, but for this specific string, it appears to be a mix of hex- and octal- encoded letters

```
"\x53\x54\117\103\113\x5f\103\x48\105\x43\113"
```

- \xFF - Hex
- \000 - Octal

The sequence above is encoded as follows (where `x` is hex and `8` is octal): `xx888x8x8x8`

This sequence may be random or intentional. Assuming it's random, the following function may be used to encode any string in like manner using [`random_int()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php) for selecting encoding method at random.

```php
<?php
function hex_octal_rand_encode($s) {
  $result = '';

  foreach (str_split($s) as $c) {
    $d = ord($c);

    // select encoding method at random (0 = hex, 1 = oct)
    $result .= (random_int(0, 1) === 0)
                ? '\\x' . dechex($d)
                : '\\'  . decoct($d);
  }

  return $result;
}

// Test
$input = "STOCK_CHECK";

$encoded = hex_octal_rand_encode($input);
echo sprintf("Encoded: %s\n", $encoded);

$cmd = sprintf('return "%s";', $encoded);
echo sprintf("Decoded: %s\n", eval($cmd));
?>
```

Sample outputs (notice the encoded value changes):

```
Encoded: \x53\x54\117\103\x4b\137\x43\x48\x45\x43\x4b
Decoded: STOCK_CHECK
```

```
Encoded: \x53\124\x4f\x43\113\x5f\x43\110\x45\x43\x4b
Decoded: STOCK_CHECK
```

```
Encoded: \123\124\x4f\x43\113\137\x43\x48\105\x43\113
Decoded: STOCK_CHECK
```

Comment: thank you I got this one but could you explain why encoded value is changes ?

Comment: It changes during each run because I'm using `random_int()` in this helper to emulate what the original obfuscator might be doing to return a mix of hex- and octal- encoded values.